# VueJS hydration map dom nodes to components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this requirement and I am looking for possible solution using VueJS, because it has this nice feature of hydration already rendered HTML from the server.

I have Vue components that have no template specified in the .vue file, but they should attach (the hydration part) to the dom elements and work with it. I have only one doubt for attaching child components.

Example would be nice...

```
<div class="page-component">
 <h1 v-text="pageTitle">Page Title</h1>

 <div class="child-component">
  <h2 v-text="childTitle">Child Title</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have two components, first is PageComponent that should handle the v-text in the h1 as part of the root dom element with class .page-component. And I have the second component ChildComponent that should attach to the dom element with class .child-component and handle the v-text in the h2.

I currently cannot understand how this can be done without specifying the template in the .vue file that matches this layout. I could see that if I do SSR render with the vue SSR render package, this is mapped correctly. But I would like to know if there's a way to create this templateless components that will use what's rendered from the server (but any server, because in my case I use different server that runs in Java, and I cannot use the npm SSR package), but then also I would like to be able to attach the components correctly to their respective portion in the whole html document.

I tried to do something but the problem is that when the PageComponent is created and attached like this: new PageComponent().$mount('.page-component'), it tries to interpolate everything that is vue related, in this case it will try to interpolate both v-text attributes and this will break because the childTitle prop is part of the ChildComponent class.

Summary, if there's a way to tell the PageComponent at which point (dom subtree) it should hand-over the control for interpolation to a child component instead of trying to attach event handlers and interpolate it by itself.

I hope my case is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to serve an HTML page from your Java server (hence without using Vue SSR), and to "hydrate" it on Client side with your Vue components, but without having to duplicate your HTML page structure within these components templates (hence you describe them as "*templateless*").

Furthermore, you want the dynamic data to come from each Component, without having to specify everything in the top level component ("*it should hand-over the control for interpolation to a child component*")

Unfortunately, whatever Vue Components composition you setup, the compilation ("*interpolation*") takes place in the template where you use them:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Compilation-Scope

> Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in the child scope.

In the case of your code example, this means that Vue expects both `pageTitle` and `childTitle` variables to be defined in your `"page-component"` Component (whether as data, props, computed properties…)

**Unless** you use [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots), which require a specific syntax:

```js
Vue.component('my-child-component', {
  template: '<div><slot :childTitle="myChildTitle"></slot></div>',
  data() {
    return {
      myChildTitle: 'Child Title from my-child-component',
    };
  },
});

function activateVue() {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Page Title from page-component',
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="if (typeof Vue === 'undefined') {alert('Vue is not loaded yet');} else {activateVue();}">Activate Vue</button>

<div class="page-component" id="app">
  <h1 v-text="pageTitle">Page Title from server</h1>

  <div class="child-component" is="my-child-component">
    <div slot-scope="{childTitle}">
      <h2 v-text="childTitle">Child Title from server</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@^2.5"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know!

Comment: Ok, I tried this... but is not quite clean because I have to define all the variables form within the child component into the parent component and list them in the slot-scope attribute, otherwise it wont work. I like to be able to keep them separate, and just tell Vue to skip interpolatin specific subtree so that I can render it with different component.

Comment: Yep unfortunately everything comes at a price… Given that you have very specific requirements that do not fit the common Vue usage, you also have to use complicated workarounds to make it match your needs.